# Vue.js : in nested navigation url changes but screen doesn't and I want to change screen to child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm trying to change the screen with a button, like a login button or something, what's wrong with my code please?

My router.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Home from "../components/Backbone.vue";
import Login from "../components/Login.vue";
import BookStore from "../components/BookStore.vue";
import TMP from "../components/Shopping.vue";
import ContactUs from "../components/Contact-Us.vue";
import BooksList from "../components/Display-Books.vue";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

export default new VueRouter({
mode: "history",
base: process.env.BASE_URL,
routes:[
{
  path: "/", name: "Home", component: Home,
},
{
  path: "/login",
  name: "Login",
  component: Login,
},
{
  path: "/contactus",
  name: "Contact Us",
  component: ContactUs,
},
{
  path: "/bookstore",
  name: "BookStore",
  component: BookStore,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'listofbooks',
      name: "ListofBooks",
      component: BooksList,
    },
  ],
},
],
});
```

The page I made button in it to navigate to the other screen
What's wrong with this? url changes to the child component but my screen remains on the same page! the same route!

```
 <button @click="BooksList()">Go to Store</button>
 

 <script>
 export default {
 props: {
 msg: String,
 },
 methods: {
    BooksList() {
      let self = this;
      self.$router.push({name:"ListofBooks"});
   },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: do you have `router-view` somewhere inside `BookStore` component?

Comment: No, I don't. but I tested this one and loaded the component below the current one!
but I want the whole screen to change.

Comment: in you current configuration. for route `/bookstore/listofbooks`, the `BooksList` component will be visible inside `BookStore` component, given that there's `router-view` inside the `BookStore` component.